# Using reduce() to find min and max values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have this code for a class where I'm supposed to use the `reduce()` method to find the min and max values in an array. However, we are required to use only a single call to reduce. The return array should be of size 2, but I know that the `reduce()` method always returns an array of size 1.

I'm able to obtain the minimum value using the code below, however I don't know how to obtain the max value in that same call. I assume that once I do obtain the max value that I just push it to the array after the `reduce()` method finishes.

```js
/**
 * Takes an array of numbers and returns an array of size 2,
 * where the first element is the smallest element in items,
 * and the second element is the largest element in items.
 *
 * Must do this by using a single call to reduce.
 *
 * For example, minMax([4, 1, 2, 7, 6]) returns [1, 7]
 */
function minMax(items) {
  var minMaxArray = items.reduce(
    (accumulator, currentValue) => {
      return (accumulator < currentValue ? accumulator : currentValue);
    }
  );

  return minMaxArray;
}
```

Comment: It appears you forgot to actually ask a question. Please review [ask].

Comment: `but I know that the reduce() method always returns an array of size 1` - this is incorrect. Also, reduce is just a method to iterate over an array with a callback, think about what other variables you can have in scope inside your `minMax` method that you can use in the iterator. Hint: From your description, you don't necessarily have to use the return value of `reduce` at all.

Comment: Read the [reduce() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) and change the `initValue` of `accumulator`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The trick consist in provide an empty Array as initialValue Parameter

```
arr.reduce(callback, [initialValue])
```

> initialValue [Optional] Value to use as the first argument to the
>   first call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first
>   element in the array will be used.

So the code would look like this:

```
function minMax(items) {
    return items.reduce((acc, val) => {
        acc[0] = ( acc[0] === undefined || val < acc[0] ) ? val : acc[0]
        acc[1] = ( acc[1] === undefined || val > acc[1] ) ? val : acc[1]
        return acc;
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: This answer has the advantage of working for arbitrary ordered types (e.g. strings), rather than just numerics, which is a nice generalization. One possible optimization would be to make the `initialValue` be `[items[0], items[0]]`, so you can avoid special casing `undefined`, simplifying the min/max calculations on each call to `if (val < acc[0]) acc[0] = val;` and `if (val > acc[1]) acc[1] = val;`

Answer (score 55):

In **ES6** you can use spread operator. One string solution:

```
 Math.min(...items)
```

Comment: Is asking for the Min and the Max.

Comment: Nice. I did't know you can use Math.min like this. I've been doing Math.min(a,b) only.

Comment: This crashes with big arrays

Comment: To elaborate on @JimmyKane answer, if you use big arrays, i.e. supply `Math.min()` with many arguments:

> "you run the risk of exceeding the JavaScript engine's argument length limit. The consequences of applying a function with too many arguments (think more than tens of thousands of arguments) vary across engines (JavaScriptCore has hard-coded argument limit of 65536), ..."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions

Answer (score 14):

You can use array as return value:

```
function minMax(items) {
    return items.reduce(
        (accumulator, currentValue) => {
            return [
                Math.min(currentValue, accumulator[0]), 
                Math.max(currentValue, accumulator[1])
            ];
        }, [Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MIN_VALUE]
    );
}
```

Comment: +1, however `MIN_VALUE` is confusingly the smallest *positive* value (>0). You'd better use `Number.INFINITY` and `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`

Comment: @Bergi I think you mean `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`... there is no `Number.INFINITY`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use do like this. There can be any number of arguments.

```
function minValue(...args) {
    const min = args.reduce((acc, val) => {
        return acc < val ? acc : val;
    });
    return min;
}

function maxValue(...args) {
    const max= args.reduce((acc, val) => {
        return acc > val ? acc : val;
    });
    return max;
}
```

Comment: This is the right solution. I failed to understand why everyone is using the `Math`'s functions when, clearly, they are not required.

Comment: @attacomsian I fail to understand why use `reduce`, when it's not required since it's just re-creating what `Math` already does for you.

Answer (score 3):

The solution using `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` functions:

```js
function minMax(items) {
    var minMaxArray = items.reduce(function (r, n) {
            r[0] = (!r[0])? n : Math.min(r[0], n);
            r[1] = (!r[1])? n : Math.max(r[1], n);
            return r;
        }, []);

    return minMaxArray;
}

console.log(minMax([4, 1, 2, 7, 6]));
```

Answer (score 3):

As the reduce call isn't really needed at all, you could have some fun with it

```js
let items = [62, 3, 7, 9, 33, 6, 322, 67, 853];

let arr = items.reduce((w,o,r,k,s=Math)=>[s.min.apply(0, k),s.max.apply(0, k)],[]);

console.log(arr);
```

All you'd really need is `let minMaxArray = [Math.min.apply(0,items), Math.max.apply(0,items)]`

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Solution using only `Math.min` and `Math.max`:

⚠️
This will not work if you use big arrays, i.e. supply `Math.min()` with many arguments as *"**you run the risk of exceeding the JavaScript engine's argument length limit**. The consequences of applying a function with too many arguments (think more than tens of thousands of arguments) vary across engines (JavaScriptCore has hard-coded argument limit of 65536), because the limit (indeed even the nature of any excessively-large-stack behavior) is unspecified. Some engines will throw an exception."* [from MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions).

```
function minMax(items) {
  return [
      Math.min.apply(null, items),
      Math.max.apply(null, items)
  ]
}
```

... or if you prefer [ES6's Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const minMax = items => [
  Math.min(...items),
  Math.max(...items)
]
```

### 2. Solution using `Array.prototype.reduce`, `Math.min` and `Math.max`

```
function minMax(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    return [
      Math.min(cur, acc[0]),
      Math.max(cur, acc[1])
    ]
  }, [Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY]);
}
```

... or shortened:

```
const minMax = items =>
  items.reduce((acc, cur) =>
    [Math.min(cur, acc[0]), Math.max(cur, acc[1])],
    [Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY]
  )
```

### 3. Solution including sensible validations

```
function minMax(items) {
  let newItems = []
  const isArray = Array.isArray(items)
  const onlyHasNumbers = !items.some(i => isNaN(parseFloat(i)))

  // only proceed if items is a non-empty array of numbers
  if (isArray && items.length > 0 && onlyHasNumbers) {
    newItems = items.reduce((acc, cur) => [
        Math.min(cur, acc[0]),
        Math.max(cur, acc[1])
      ], [Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY])
  }

  return newItems
}
```

> Documentation for [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)
>
> Documentation for [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Using_Math.max())
>
> Documentation for [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 3):

To get min and max value of an array using reduce function

```
const ArrayList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 20, 0];
const LargestNum = ArrayList.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      return Math.max(prev, curr)
});
const MinNum = ArrayList.reduce((prev,curr)=>{
      return Math.min(prev,curr)
});
console.log(LargestNum);
console.log(MinNum);
```

Comment: In your example it works only because the latest values of the array are `20` and `0`, and are the last one compared. Just try to put the min and max values at the beginning of your array, and we will see if your code is still working :)

Comment: After putting 0,20 in the begaining of array still working no issue  the output is 20,0

Comment: Ok I read too quickly your answer, after reading again, it seems that it is correct. My apologies

Answer (score 3):

```
const values = [1,2,3,4,5];
const [first] = values;
const maxValue = values.reduce((acc, value) => Math.max(acc, value), first);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of reduce vs Array

```
const result = Array(-10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).reduce((a,b)=>{ return (a<b) ? a : b })
```

You may want to use the same against getting length of strings

```
 const result = Array("ere","reeae","j","Mukono Municipality","Sexy in the City and also").reduce((a,b)=>{ return (a.length<b.length) ? a : b })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [8978, 'lol', -78, 989, NaN, null, undefined, 6, 9, 55, 989];


let minMax = arr.reduce(([min, max], v) => [
                Math.min(min, v) || min,
                Math.max(max, v) || max], [Infinity, -Infinity]);


console.log(minMax);
```

How it works:

1. `|| min` check is `v` number.
2. `[Infinity, -Infinity]` is `.reduce` initial value
3. It use js [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) assignment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain your answer. Don't just write code.  **For Help take a look at "[How to answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)"**

Comment: try this
let arr = [8978, 'lol', 78, 989, NaN, 0, null, undefined, 6, 9, 55, 989];

Answer (score 0):

We can accomplish this by declaring an empty array as the accumulator value for the reduce function, then carrying out a different set of operations on the last iteration of the reduce method. We do this by passing all four parameters to the reduce method (total, item, index, array) and using a comparison of the index to the array length to do something different on that last iteration.

```
var prices = [32.99, 21.99, 6.99, 4.99, 12.99, 8.98, 5.99];

var highLowPrices = prices.reduce(function(accumulatorArray, price, index, pricesArray){
    if (index === pricesArray.length-1){
        accumulatorArray.push(price);
        var returnArray = [];
        accumulatorArray.sort(function(price1, price2){
            return price1 - price2;
        });
        var lowestPrice = accumulatorArray[0];
        var highestPrice = accumulatorArray[accumulatorArray.length-1];
        returnArray.push(lowestPrice);
        returnArray.push(highestPrice);
        return returnArray;
    } else {
        accumulatorArray.push(price);
        return accumulatorArray;
    }
}, []);

console.log(highLowPrices);
```

I've intentionally used a few more steps than necessary and used semantically verbose variable names to make the logic clearer.

`if (index === pricesArray.length-1)` means that on the last iteration of the reduce method through the prices array, a different set of operations occurs. Up to that point, we are merely recreating the prices array, which is trivial. But on the last iteration, after fully recreating the prices array, we do something different. We create another empty array, the one we intend to return. We then sort through the 'accumulatorArray' variable - which is the prices array, recreated, sorting it from lowest to highest. We now take the lowest price and highest price and store them in variables. Having sorted the array in ascending order, we know that the lowest is at index 0 and the highest, at index array.length - 1. We then push those variables into our previously declared return array. And instead of returning the accumulator variable itself, we return our own specially declared return array. The result is an array with the lowest price and then the highest price.

Answer (score 0):

**Code to get max value in an Array using reduce function in Javascript**

```
const movements = [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, 70, 1300];

const large = movements.reduce(function (acc, mov) {
if (acc > mov) {
return acc;
} else {
  return mov;
 }
}, movements[0]);

console.log(large);
```

**Answer is : 3000**

Answer (score -1):

I know this has been answered but I went off of [@Sergey Zhukov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442659/3689450) (which seems incomplete) and was able to get the min and max values in 2 lines:

```
let vals = [ numeric values ]
let min = Math.min.apply(undefined, vals) 
let max = Math.max.apply(undefined, vals)
```

I do see the value in `Array.reduce`, but with such a super simple use case, **and** so long as you understand what `Function.apply` does, this would be my goto solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
let x = [4, 1, 2, 7, 6]
const r = x.reduce((acumularo, currenvalue)=>{
    if(acumularo[0]>currenvalue) acumularo[0] = currenvalue
    if(acumularo[1]<currenvalue) acumularo[1] = currenvalue
    return acumularo
},[x[0],x[0]])
console.log(r)
console.log(r[0]+r[1])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function minMax(items) {
  var minMaxArray = [Math.min(...items), Math.max(...items)]
  return minMaxArray;
}
```

Comment: What value does this answer add to existing solutions by reiterating the same thing and not accounting for the question having a **requirement** to use `reduce`?