# Reduce of empty array with no initial value after testing a specific use case

Tags: javascript, sorting, filter, functional-programming, reduce

Variable `min` will contain the sum of the 4 smallest items in a given array.
Variable `max` will contain the sum of the 4 largest items in a given array.

**JS:**

```
function main() {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  const min = arr.sort().filter((element, index, array) => element !== array[array.length - 1]).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    return accumulator + currentValue
  })
  const max = arr.sort().filter((element, index, array) => element !== array[0]).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    return accumulator + currentValue
  })
  console.log(min, max)
}

main()
```

As expected, `[1,2,3,4,5]` will result in 10, 14. However, if the given array is `[5,5,5,5,5]`, the program will return `TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value`.

Why is this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why ? Because you have not specified an initial value in .reduce - just put 0 as second parameter to that function. // Also, your filtering logic is not matching goal description you gave - but that's another thing altogether.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576241/javascript-using-reduce-to-find-min-and-max-values

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that array contains `5` elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all elements are the same,
the condition `element !== array[array.length - 1]` will be false for all elements, because all elements are the same as the last.
Therefore the result of the `filter(...)` will be an empty array,
and so you get the error that you got.

In fact this implementation is quite flawed.
It's better to work with the `index` rather than the element values:

```
function main(arr) {
  const count = 4;

  const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  const sum = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

  const min = sorted
    .filter((element, index) => index < count)
    .reduce(sum);

  const max = sorted
    .filter((element, index) => index >= arr.length - count)
    .reduce(sum);

  console.log(min, max);
}

main([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
main([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]);
```

I slipped in some other improvements as well:

- Make the array a parameter of the function, for easier testing
- Don't sort the array twice, once is enough
- As [@Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4385889/andrew) pointed out in a comment, `arr.sort()` does not sort integers properly, you need to pass it a comparator function to get the intended effect
- Reduce duplicated logic: extracted `sum` function and `count` variable
- Replace code block with inlined lambda expression

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I overlooked that, fixed now

Comment: can we cache `arr.length` as well?

Comment: @CodeYogi Any improvement that might bring, I think it would be negligible.

Comment: @CodeYogi `arr.length` is a property of the array object. It is already "cached" in that sense.