# Sum array without Highest and lower number js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve the task (Sum all the numbers of the array (in F# and Haskell you get a list) except the highest and the lowest element (the value, not the index!).
(The highest/lowest element is respectively only one element at each edge, even if there are more than one with the same value!))

This is my code but I am getting NaN

```js
function sumArray(array) {
  var sum;
  array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
  for (var i = 1; i < array.length - 2; i++) {
    return sum += array[i];
  }

}
console.log(
  sumArray([6, 2, 1, 8, 10])
)
```

Comment: what is your expectation for an empty array? or an array with only one value in it as it will be the highest and the lowest at the same time.

Comment: `var sum = 0;` will likely help and move the return outside the loop

Comment: `array.length - 2` should be `array.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. initialise the sum=0
2. move the return to outside the loop
3. loop until `<length-1`, not 2

Note in the second example I use reduce to get max and min since

> both spread (...) and apply will either fail or return the wrong result if the array has too many elements, because they try to pass the array elements as function parameters.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

```js
function sumArray(array) {
  var sum = 0;
  array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
  for (var i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(
  sumArray([6, 2, 1, 8, 10])
)

// or not sorting
let arr = [6, 2, 1, 8, 10];
const max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return Math.max(a, b);
})
const min = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return Math.min(a, b);
})
let sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0); // add 
sum -= (min + max);
console.log(sum)

// using one reduce (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43576388/295783):
let minmax = arr.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue) => {
    return [
      Math.min(currentValue, accumulator[0]),
      Math.max(currentValue, accumulator[1])
    ];
  }, [Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MIN_VALUE]
)
sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0); // add 
sum -= (minmax[0] + minmax[1]);
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: I don't know why you keep sorting the array. You don't need that to spot the max and min values from the collection.

Comment: I could Math.max/min it but then it is identical to the other answer

Comment: @nicodp - I have added a sortless version that does not fail on large arrays

Comment: Updated to add one version with only one reduce for the minmax

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- `sum` needs an initial value, i.e. 0
- You `return` *inside* the loop, so the loop can only do one iteration, ... ever. Move it after the loop
- You are not summing the one but last (ordered) value. Use `i < array.length - 1`
- Your algorithm relies on `sort` which gives it a time of complexity of *O(nlogn)*. You can do this in *O(n)* if you use `Math.min` and `Math.max`:

```js
function sumArray(array) {
    return array.length < 2 ? 0
         : array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) - Math.min(...array) - Math.max(...array);
}
console.log(
    sumArray([6, 2, 1, 8, 10])
)
```

NB: This is ES6 code, supported by all main browsers, with IE being one notable exception.

For older browsers:

```js
function sumArray(array) {
    return array.length < 2 ? 0
         : array.reduce(function (a, b) {
               return a + b;
           }) - Math.min.apply(null, array) - Math.max.apply(null, array);
}
console.log(
    sumArray([])
)
```

For very large arrays it may be necessary to get minimum and maximum values via `reduce` as the number of arguments that can be passed to a function call is limited.

Comment: This however is ES5+. A bit over the head of OP I would think and not running on all browsers

Comment: @mplungjan She did not specify that she needed her code to be corrected, she outlined the task, and asked for a solution.

Comment: There is this though: `However, both spread (...) and apply will either fail or return the wrong result if the array has too many elements, because they try to pass the array elements as function parameters.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max